# Getting 404 when calling a post method on Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have an API controller which have standard GET,POST and Delete actions.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    //Get
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post([FromBody] TestUser testUser, string tempPassword, role = "Guest")
    {

    }
}
```

Now I am adding a new action using:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/[controller]/UpdateRole")]
public async Task Post(string email, List<string> roles)
{
}
```

When I am trying to call the API using postman ,

Type : POST
Endpoint : http://localhost/api/users/UpdateRole

Request body:

```
{
    "email":"something@mail.com",
    "roles":["S1","s3"]
}
```

But I am getting a `404` as response back. On server I can see ,

> the application completed without reading the entire request body.

Comment: If your controller has a `[Route]` attribute, and so does your action, surely your overall route is `/api/Users/api/Users/UpdateRoute` (based on your code)?

Comment: Thanks @John, That's the case. It worked after changing the Route to    [Route("UpdateRole")], just a quick followup , though it's hitting the breakpoint now , I can see bot email and roles as null. Any ideas.

Comment: @John, Your comment fixed my original issue though If you would like to post the solution , I will mark that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your overall route is `/api/Users/api/Users/UpdateRoute` because of how `RouteAttribute` works.

```
[Route("a")]
public class MyController
{
    [Route("a/b")]
    public IActionResult MyAction()
    {
    }
}
```

The above will have a route of `/a/a/b` because the action route is appended to the controller route in this case.

Your options are:

- Change the controller route to `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]` and remove the action route, in which case the example above would become `/MyController/MyAction`
- Change the action route to simply `[Route("b")]`, in which case the full route would be `a/b`
- Use an absolute path for the action route `[Route("/a/b")]`, in which case the controller route would be ignored and the full route will simply be `/a/b`.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) for more information about routing.

As for your issue with `null` values, ASP.NET Core is currently expecting `email` and `roles` as querystring parameters. Instead, you should create a model for your request body:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And then change your action to accept it:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/[controller]/UpdateRole")]
public async Task Post([FromBody]MyModel model)
{

}
```